# Visual Studio 2005 crashes when i open a c++ project or solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

i have quite a large solution with 10 projects (I am new to Visual Studio so be forgiving if I don't get the terminology right). One of the projects is a C++ project that would compile to a .dll. I have a new machine so everything is freshly installed. However, every time I try to open the c++ project VS crashes.

I then tried creating a new c++ solution/project but as soon as it is created and the solution explorer is presented VS crashes. I have searched Stackoverflow and there was something that may have worked but the reference to hot fix KB947315 is not accessible. I have tried to find the hot fix but to no avail.

I tried debugging VS2005 with VS2010 but did not get far.

My OS is windows 7 and I have included a screen shot of the VS help about for the version

Comment: Have you tried running VS2005 as administrator? And needless to say, if you have VS2010 available, a more prudent approach might be to upgrade the solution to VS2010.

Comment: One of the problems was that if you have a source code file (or possibly a temporary file referenced in the build process: *.obj etc.) in your solution which full path is longer than 260 characters, then IDE might crash. You mentioned the solution is large and you could put it into certain subdirectory, so reaching such a long path is basically possible. Trying moving solution close to the root to eliminate the long path issue.

Comment: What are the pit falls when upgrading from 2005 to 2010? I'm not prepared at this time to retest the entire solution. it is made up of 5 different projects.